# Redis - Default snapshotting configuration

Tags: redis

I am playing with Redis cluster as an experiment and I used an existing script to create and run the cluster: [Create Redis Cluster](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/utils/create-cluster/create-cluster)

Everything runs just fine and I don't specify any "save" parameters in the command line while starting redis cluster. However, when I specify --save 60 10000 in this script, I see dump.rdb file being created when I write some data to the database.

Then I happened to look at the code  [[server.c]](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/server.c), where the below functions is being called:

```
line 2323:     appendServerSaveParams(60,10000); /* save after 1 minute and 10000 changes */
```

As per my understanding, the rdb file should have been created even when I didn't specify any "--save" option in the command line while starting redis server.

Can someone explain this behavior? I am trying to understand the default snapshotting configuration when no "--save"  option is specified while starting Redis instances using command line (hence not using Redis.conf).